# Можно ли запустить js скрипт через запрос?

Tags: javascript, java

Пишу функцию для перезагрузки usb модема через вебморду. 
Сейчас это делаю с помощью selenium. Открываю в headless режиме через fierfox страницу модема, нажимаю на кнопку "Перезагрузить" затем на подтверждение "Ок". Но страница не всегда перезагружается. Иногда веб драйвер не видит кнопку и выдает ошибку (хотя стоит ожидание кнопки длинной в час). 
Посмотрел код кнопки, при нажатии на нее выполняется скрипт reboot.js
Могу ли я его запустить отправляя запрос? 
На всякий случай привожу пример кода, который сейчас нажимает кнопку "Перезагрузить".

```
driver.get("http://192.168.8.1/html/reboot.html");

   WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 3600)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("span_reboot_apply_button")));
   ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 5);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   WebElement element_2 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 3600)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("pop_confirm")));
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element_2);

    System.out.println("Перезагружаем модем...");
```

Comment: может посмотреть код `reboot.js`? скорее всего там есть запрос, который вам нужен, и тогда легче просто вызвать его

Comment: Вот файл reboot.js, ссылок нет:
function() {
  if (!isButtonEnable('reboot_apply_button')) {
    return;
  }
  button_enable('reboot_apply_button', '0');
  showConfirmDialog(system_setting_reboot, reboot, function() {
    button_enable('reboot_apply_button', '1');
  }, null, function() {
    button_enable('reboot_apply_button', '1');
  });
  return false;
}

Comment: После нажатия на кнопку "Перезагрузить" выскакивает еще окошко с просьбой подтвердить перезагрузку. При нажатии "Ок" происходт перезагрузка, на кнопке "Ок" только один скрипт, вот такой:
function() {
  clearDialog();

  if (typeof(okFunc) == 'function') {
    okFunc();
  }
  okFunc = null;
  cancelFunc = null;
  removeFunc = null;
  g_main_displayingPromptStack.pop();
  hiddenSelect(false);
  return false;
}
Не понимаю, как происходит перезагрузка.

Comment: Попробуйте в консоли разработчика в браузере на вкладке Сеть посмотреть какие запросы уходят при нажатии кнопки ОК

Comment: попробывал отследить выполнение скриптов при нажатии на кнопку. Почему то скрипт reboot.js который виден в эвенте кнопки вообще не фигурирует при просмотре вкладки "Network".
Копировал curl запрос скриптов (prompt.js) которые выполнились при нажатии и попробовал их выполнить - не выполнился.
Вот скрин - https://habrastorage.org/webt/5c/b0/ee/5cb0ee4b814a1291762298.png

Comment: отловил запросы которые происходят при нажатии кнопки...и ничего. Те три запроса которые отловил ничего особенного не делают при выполнении. Два показывают картинку с сообщение о том, что начата и закончена перезагрузка, другой возвращает информацию о модеме. Разве такое может быть, что при нажатии на кнопку ничего не регистрировалось, но выполнялось?

Comment: @RomulFobos вообще всё может быть, например при первом запросе загружается javascript и запускается на исполнение, при таком варианте первый раз его видно не будет, но если он делает какие-то запросы их всё равно должно быть видно. На скрине у вас фильтр только по js запросам. Анализировать лучше все. Тот запрос который показывает что начата перезагрузка по идее должен её и начинать.

Comment: И судя по коду при нажатии кнопки OK должна вызываться функция okFunc(), её код вы смотрели? Можете дополнить вопрос.